# ¿Es correcto decir "déjeme saber"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

A veces escucho una frase como "Déjeme saber cuando venza el permiso" para indicar que debo avisar al orador la fecha de vencimiento.  Me parece una traducción directa del inglés de "Let me know..." y sería mejor decir "Avíseme..." o incluso "Hágame saber..." porque la petición es de un acto afirmativo.

Pero la herramienta de contexto [reverso.net](https://context.reverso.net/translation/spanish-english/d%C3%A9jeme+saber) proporciona muchos ejemplos del uso de dicha frase y es utilizada a menudo por mi compañera de trabajo (que habla español como lengua materna a pesar de haber crecido en EEUU).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Según [el DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/dejar):

> Debe evitarse el empleo de la expresión *dejar saber* con el sentido de ‘informar o hacer saber’, calco censurable del inglés *let know*.

La Fundéu reproduce un [artículo](https://www.fundeu.es/noticia/traidores-4415/) de Listín Diario (República Dominicana) que llega al punto de llamarlo una "traición", aunque esto quizá es un poco excesivo.

Como indicas, las expresiones correctas son "Avíseme" o "Hágame saber", entre otras.

En España nunca he oído la expresión "dejar saber". Parece ser más común en Latinoamérica, debido a la influencia de Estados Unidos.

Comment: Realmente, la Fundéu no dice eso, sino que recoge un artículo publicado en la República Dominicana que sí lo dice. Pero, quitando este pequeño detalle, me parece una buena respuesta.

Comment: Dicho lo cual, preveo que este Spanglish se acabará adoptando más y más

Comment: Jajaja, yo tengo un amigo dominicano que dice "llamar pa trás" en vez de "devolver la llamada", claro por "call back".